# Numerical Integration wrt one variable in a multivariate expression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I want to calculate the expression in the image below 
[image]

I have written the following code

```
syms l k ;
T = 5;
r_c = 100;
lambda = 1 / (pi * (r_c ^ 2));
r_b = 141.4;
ro = pi * lambda * (r_b ^ 2);
N = 5;
etha = N * factorial(N)^(-N);
theta_t = pi / 6;
theta_r = pi / 2;
c_r = theta_r / (2 * pi);
c_t = theta_t / (2 * pi);
M_r = 10;
M_t = 10;
m_r = -10;
m_t = -10;
a = [ M_r * M_t , M_r * m_t , m_r * M_t , m_r * m_t ];
a_bar = a / ( M_r * M_t);
b = [ c_r * c_t , c_r * ( 1 - c_t) , (1 - c_r) * c_t , ( 1 - c_r ) * ( 1 - c_t )];
mu = exp(0.577);

fun = @(t) symprod( exp(ro * b(k) * ( exp(-l * etha * T * a_bar(k) * t ) ...
    - t * exp(-l * etha * T * a_bar(k) ))) * ...
    ((1- exp(-l * mu * etha * T * a_bar(k) * t ))/...
    ( 1 - exp(-l * mu * etha * T * a_bar(k)) ))^ ...
    (l * etha * T * b(k) * a_bar(k) * ro * t)  , k , 1 , 4 );

p =  ro * exp( -ro ) * symsum( (-1)^(l+1) * nchoosek(N,l) * integral( @(t) fun , 0 , 1)    ...
    , l , 1 , N)  ;
```

where p is going to be the expression value for input T = 5.
The code is not working giving back error :

> Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found
>   'function_handle'.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `integral(fun,...`

Comment: @AnderBiguri tried that too , didn't work